# Creating a circle equation that has a specific slope at a specific point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

basically I need to create a circle that will connect with a linear equation at a point so that it is both a continuous and smooth transition, meaning at that point the circle needs to have both the same derivative and y value as the linear equation.
Right now I'm playing around with the equation (ax + b)^2 + (ax + c)^2 = 1 
where a b and c are all constants that I'm trying to find out so that when x = 1, y = 4 and the derivative is also 4. I know how to get a line to fit a circle (a tangent) so that its smooth and continuous but I don't know how to create a circle to fit a line, help!

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  I think you are saying, you are given a point $P$ on a line $L$ and you want to find a circle tangent to $L$ at $P$.  Is this correct?  If so, there are infinitely many such circles....just make the perpendicular to $L$ at $P$, take any point on that as the center of your circle.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to format your math expressions correctly.

Comment: Infinitely many circles touch on either side of a given straight line at a given point..

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

All the tangents circles with center lying on the perpendicular at the tangent line at that point are solutions.

[image]